# Git: push-pull on working copies

Tags: git

I am starting to use "Git" for version control. I've initialized my repo. C:\Myrepo and committed several files.

```
git init
git add .
git commit
```

Then I cloned this "Myrepo".

```
git clone C:\Myrepo c:\Newrepo
```

Further I want to pull changes from Newrepo back to Myrepo.

```
#c:\Myrepo>git pull c:\Newrepo
#From c:\Newrepo
# * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
#Already up-to-date.
```

It's OK.

BUT the I want to pull the changes from c:\Myrepo to c:\Newrepo then I am getting fatal as follow

```
#c:\Newrepo>git pull c:\Myrepo
#fatal: 'c:\Myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
#fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I pull or push the changes from c:\Myrepo to new formed repository? What procedure should I use? How to correct use push/pull? Is it possible without bare repo? Do I need to somehow config the repos?

---

Still have problem with "push" command... How to create repo to accept push? I am still creating repo just with "git init" if so I am not able to push to this dir?
How to do the push? It must be initialized as "bare" repo to enable "push" or is it possible to push to working copy repo?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: try `git pull C:\Myrepo\.git`. although it should work with your path too (as it does with Newrep)

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1):

From new repo, you can do

`git pull origin`

Origin is the remote pointing to the `MyRepo` and it is automatically setup when you clone.

I am not really sure why `git pull c:\Myrepo` failed though `git pull c:\Newrepo` worked. But a `git pull origin` should give you a better idea to see if you had done something different while setting up that is not apparent from what you have posted here.

PS: In Git, there is no concept of working copies. All are repos, with there being a distinction between bare ( which don't have a working directory) and non-bare repos.

Answer (score 0):

Please set up a remote and pull and push with that. It will make subsequent pushes/pulls/fetches less of a hassle.

edit:

take a look at the manual for:

```
git remote
git branch
git push
```

so that you know what the requirements are for regular pushing and pulling to and from repositories. Ie, You don't want to be specifying a full url/path every time you do that.

Comment: Adam, this doesn't really answer the question. Better suited as a comment.

Comment: if you are using one branch, you should be able to just `git pull` and `git push` to sync.