# Git - multiple working copies without bare copy in between

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch

Similar to:

- [Git On A Keystick & GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982417/git-on-a-keystick-github)
- [Using GIT on USB stick for "travelling code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389894/using-git-on-usb-stick-for-travelling-code)
- [git: how to properly share local copy between multiple PCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127029/git-how-to-properly-share-local-copy-between-multiple-pcs)
- [Git: push-pull on working copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233508/git-push-pull-on-working-copies)
- [How to convert existing non-empty directory into a Git working directory and push files to a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)

I'm trying to figure out the workflow steps to accomplish the following:

1. Having worked locally on "home", I want to start a repository in `W:\DEV\proj1`

   - `git init W:\DEV\proj1`
   - `cd W:\DEV\proj1`
   - `git add *`
   - `git commit -m"1st home"`
2. I then want to clone this repo to "portable" somewhere else (i.e. a usbkey), lets say `P:\DEV\roam1`

   - `git clone . P:\DEV\roam1`
3. Then I want to be able to do work in *either location* ("home" or "portable") and sync changes back and forth.

   - *(in portable)*

     - `// new file f1.txt`
     - `git add *`
     - `git commit -m"1st portable"`
     - `git ???`   -- sync f1.txt > "home"?
   - *(in home)*

     - `// new file f2.txt`
     - `git add *`
     - `git commit -m"2nd home"`
     - `git ???`   -- sync f2.txt > "portable"
   - repeat

**Part A)** I think I understand how to clone and sync to a "centralized hub", i.e. github or putting a bare repo on a usb stick and cloning from it whenever I'm at a new location, but I'd rather not have to clone from the portable repo every time I want to get work done *in a new place*.  Also, in the case where I just want to look at the file on a computer that doesn't have git installed.

**Part B)** Another applicable scenario is that I want to use git to basically backup a directory to an external harddrive (which pushing to a bare repo would normally be fine) but I want to **access the files** on the harddrive on another **computer without git installed**.

Comment: For **Part B**, I'm guessing just cloning to the harddrive would be fine, and then periodically running `git pull` _from_ the harddrive to get recent changes?

Comment: I'm going to look more at this post http://swoes.blogspot.com/2009/02/setting-up-git-offline-work-via-usb.html

Comment: Points for trying to distinguish your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'd rather not have to clone from the portable repo every time I want to get work done.

You won't have to, except to initialize your repo in a new location (in which case, you would clone the bare repo of your usb stick on your local environment)

Every time you want to get work done, you would:

- make sure the remote named 'origin' of your local repo points to the bare repo on the usb stick
- `git pull` (or git pull --rebase) in order to get potential changes from usb back to local
- work
- git push (back to the usb key)

You need some kind of "centralized/portable" repo to pull from/push to.

---

> not wanting the "centralized hub" to be a bare repo is that, let's say I go another computer without git and I want to just show someone a file

I would still recommend a bare repo on the usb stick, but I would add a **post-receive hook** on that bare repo, in order to update a separate working tree (*still* on the usb stick)

See "[Want to setup a hook that copies committed files to a particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16077399/6309)" as an example of such a hook.

That way, I always have, on my "centralized and portable" git repo hosting environment (ie the usb key!):

- a bare repo (I can clone/pull from/push to)
- a full working tree, up-to-date with the latest commits.

Comment: my point about not wanting the "centralized hub" to be a bare repo is that, let's say I go another computer _without git_ and I want to just show someone a file -- I need the files available on the portable device, not packed away.  I'll clarify my question.

Comment: @drzaus I have updated my answer in order to address your last point.

Comment: so basically it's like a regular git repo _(project/ -> [.git/ + "working files"])_, but the `.git` folder is the bare repo in one folder, and the working files are post-hooked to another non-git folder _([project.git/ + project.working/])_?

Comment: @drzaus yes, you have two folders on that USB key: one is the bare repo, the other is a working tree updated by the post-receive hook from the bare repo.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  just to explicitly confirm, the working tree folder is either: 1) a git repo that can commit back to the bare, or 2) just flat files for viewing only?  if #1, isn't that duplicating the .git database?  if #2, can i make changes on a non-git computer and commit them back into version control?

Comment: @drzaus 2): you checkout from the bare repo into another folder: no duplication. This is what the command (from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16077399/6309)) `git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root.git --work-tree=/path/to/your/workingtree checkout -f` does: only *one* repo involved here. No duplication.

Comment: So I think I figured out both scenarios #amiright @VonC? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20132742/1037948

Answer (score 2):

Concrete example based on @VonC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18097290/1037948).

#### DEVICES

- `LOCAL` = your local machine, i.e. `C:\MyDocuments\Whatever`
- `PORTABLE` = something else, like a USB key

#### REPOS

- `LOCAL/myproject/` = the "day-to-day" repo where you do your work, push to github, etc
- `PORTABL/myproject.git` = the bare "centralized hub" (on the usb key)
- `PORTABLE/myproject-preview` = a non-git folder containing the latest code from the repo
- `PORTABLE/myproject-working` = a git repo you can work from when not at home (basically the same as `LOCAL/myproject`

#### File Structure

*NOTE: I'm testing this all within a single folder on my computer rather than actual separate drives, YMMV*

```
-LOCAL/
   -myproject/
      -.git/
      - other files

-PORTABLE/
   -myproject.git/
       -hooks/
       -info/
       <etc>
   -myproject-preview/
      - other files
   -myproject-working/
      -.git
      - other files
```

#### CONFIG

approx commands...assumes you were working locally first before this brainstorm

```
# start at home
cd LOCAL
git init myproject
<do some work>
# suddenly you realize you want a portable hub
cd PORTABLE
# ready the dump locations (depending on what you want)
mkdir myproject-preview
mkdir myproject-working
# start the hub
git init myproject.git --bare
<make the post-receive hook, see below *not cool enough to do it from the command line>
# backup home
cd LOCAL/myproject
git remote add origin PORTABLE/myproject.git
git push origin master #this shows up in ...preview and ...working
<do more work>
```

#### Post-Receive Hook

Lovingly copied from @VonC's [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16077399/1037948) and [a random coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/oj5smw).

You can do both, or choose just "preview mode" or "portable work".

Note the use of relative paths (since we're in `PORTABLE/myproject.git/hooks/`).

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        # preview mode
        git --git-dir=../myproject.git --work-tree=../myproject-preview checkout -f
        # portable working mode (https://coderwall.com/p/oj5smw)
        GIT_WORK_TREE=../myproject-portable git checkout -f $branch
    fi
done
```